# How to make database for Multilanguage list app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, multilingual

E.g. the app is in 3 langs (en, fr, de).
I have two lists. If I change app language I want to show the values with correct translations.

I have an equipment list:

EQ_LIST

```
eq_id | group_id | title | lang
1, 1, tv | en
2, 1, la télé, fr
3, 1, Fernseher, de
```

QTY_LIST
I have another list, where I want to "log" any changes in quantity

```
qty_id | groupd_id, qty
1, 1, 3
2, 1, 6
3, 1, 8
```

group_id refers to the "tv" equipment, without to know the lang.
Embed these two tables and filter by lang, is a good way to make?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use the [built-in localization features](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization) of Android? You can make different xml resources like strings or arrays of strings for different languages.

Comment: I need to store data in room, and it would be simplier to have there the translations

Comment: @TylerV The built in localization features only work if all values are known at compile time, and if no data is coming from the server.  They don't work at all on dynamic data, and are a pain to use in a database if the data ever changes because the string ids or not stable between builds.

Comment: @froniq This is ok for a basic version, but translations are complicated.  Let's say you needed to store a computer mouse quantity.  The english translation for one mouse is "mouse", but for 2 or more it's "mice".  Some languages are even more complicated-  having different translations for 0, 1, 2, and many.  There's probably some languages with even worse quirks.  If you're going to roll your own, you may want to look at some translation libraries.  It also depends what you're trying to do.  This is ok for a school app most likely.  Its probably not enough for a paid product.

Comment: It will be a free product but later maybe can change, and can happen there will be an export to cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest

- **1** the addition of a table for the language(s) and
- **2** also extending the eq table. To incorporate a map to the language and also a map to what would be the **"base"** entry.

So perhaps have a **language** table such as :-

[image]

DDL would be :-

```
CREATE TABLE language (languageid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, languagename TEXT UNIQUE, languageshortname TEXT UNIQUE);
```

An **eq_list** table such as :-

[image]

- i.e. titleenglishmap points to a specific "base" (this would allow conversion say from le tele to television as it links all the translations).

DDL would be :-

```
CREATE TABLE eq_list (eqid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, groupid INTEGER, titleenglishmap INTEGER, languageidmap INTEGER REFERENCES language(languageid));
```

The **qty_list** table could be as it is :-

[image]

using the above you could have queries such as :-

```
SELECT qty_listid,title,qty_list,languagename  FROM qty_list 
    JOIN eq_list  ON qty_list.qty_listgroupid = eq_list.groupid
    JOIN language ON eq_list.languageidmap = language.languageid
WHERE languagename LIKE 'french'
;

SELECT qty_listid,title,qty_list,languagename FROM qty_list 
    JOIN eq_list  ON qty_list.qty_listgroupid = eq_list.groupid
    JOIN language ON eq_list.languageidmap = language.languageid
WHERE languagename LIKE 'German'
```

Which would respectively produce results:-

For **French** :-

[image]

and

For **German** :-

[image]

**SQLite Demo (includes adding Spanish and Italian)**

**First the Table Creation DDL's** :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS language (languageid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, languagename TEXT UNIQUE, languageshortname TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eq_list (eqid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, groupid INTEGER, titleenglishmap INTEGER, languageidmap INTEGER REFERENCES language(languageid));
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS AFTER INSERT ON eq_list WHEN new.languageidmap = -9999 BEGIN UPDATE eq_list SET titleenglishmap = new.eqid WHERE new.titleenglishmap = -9999; END;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS qty_list (qty_listid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, qty_listgroupid INTEGER, qty_list INTEGER);
```

- Note the TRIGGER isn't essential an @Query running an UPDATE can do what it needs.
- When you insert a new **"Base"** eq_list (e.g. English Television) you may not know the **eqid** that the **titleenglishmap** should point to so the TRIGGER (or UPDATE) reconciles this based upon a value of -9999 i.e. it will set the **titleennglishmap** value to the **eqid** value.
- Room doesn't support TRIGGERS via annotation, this could be added be via the `onOpen Callback`.

**Inserting The Languages**

To insert the 3 Languages English, French and German :-

```
INSERT INTO language (languagename,languageshortname) VALUES ('English','en'),('French','fr'),('German','de');
```

- Note that the language id's will very likely be 1,2 and 3. However, the following DOES NOT rely upon this assumption.

**Adding a Base (English) eq_list**

```
/* Add the main (English equipment note the -9999 so UPDATE (could be a TRIGGER))*/
INSERT INTO eq_list (title,groupid,languageidmap,titleenglishmap) VALUES('television',1 /* the groupid */,1,-9999);
/* make english / base title point to itself (not needed for TRIGGER)*/
UPDATE eq_list SET titleenglishmap = eqid WHERE titleenglishmap = -9999;
```

- as can be seen the UPDATE reconciles the titleenglishmap value (although the trigger has already done this)
- only one update would be needed for multiple base eq_list rows (e.g. for Telephone .... )

**Adding the translations (French and German)**

```
INSERT INTO eq_list (title,groupid,languageidmap,titleenglishmap) VALUES
    ('le tele',(SELECT groupid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'television'),(SELECT languageid FROM language WHERE languagename LIKE 'French'),(SELECT eqid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'television' )),
    ('fernsehen',(SELECT groupid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'television'),(SELECT languageid FROM language WHERE languagename LIKE 'German'),(SELECT eqid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'television' )),
    ('tv',(SELECT groupid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'television'),(SELECT languageid FROM language WHERE languagename LIKE 'English'),(SELECT eqid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'television' ))
;
```

- note that tv is effectively an alias of television (however the potential use of this has not been covered, so for all intents and purposes tv can be ignored).
- the **groupid** is taken from the **base** (television) according to the **title**
- the **languageidmap** is determined from the **name** of the language
- the **titleenglishmap** is determined according to the **eqid** of the **base** according to the **title**
- note that by using LIKE names (title and language) are not case dependant, so *french* would get *French** etc.

**Add the qty_list rows**

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO qty_list VALUES (1,1,3),(2,1,6),(3,1,8);
```

- ***The results shown above were driven from the above code.***

**The model is adaptable. Say you wanted to add Spanish and Italian.**

Then :-

**Add the New Languages** :-

```
INSERT INTO language (languagename,languageshortname) VALUES ('Spanish','es'),('Italian','it');
```

**Add the translations**

```
/* And the new equipment transalations */
INSERT INTO eq_list (title,groupid,languageidmap,titleenglishmap) VALUES
/* Spanish */
    ('televisión'/* ARG1 1 name in the language*/,(SELECT groupid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'television'),(SELECT languageid FROM language WHERE languagename LIKE 'Spanish' /* ARG 2 language */),(SELECT eqid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'television' /* ARG3 The english translation */ )),
/* Italian */
    ('television',(SELECT groupid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'television'),(SELECT languageid FROM language WHERE languagename LIKE 'Italian' /* ARG 2 language */),(SELECT eqid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'television' /* ARG3 The english translation */ ))
;
```

**DONE** that's it.

Now the following queries could be used (i.e. no different to above bar the name of the language change):-

```
SELECT qty_listid,title,qty_list,languagename  FROM qty_list 
    JOIN eq_list  ON qty_list.qty_listgroupid = eq_list.groupid
    JOIN language ON eq_list.languageidmap = language.languageid
WHERE languagename LIKE 'Spanish'
;

SELECT qty_listid,title,qty_list,languagename  FROM qty_list 
    JOIN eq_list  ON qty_list.qty_listgroupid = eq_list.groupid
    JOIN language ON eq_list.languageidmap = language.languageid
WHERE languagename LIKE 'Italian'
;
```

[image]

and :-

[image]

**Adding additional eq_list rows e.g. for Telephone**

```
INSERT INTO eq_list (title,groupid,languageidmap,titleenglishmap) VALUES('telephone',1 /* the groupid */,1,-9999);
/* make english / base title point to itself (not needed for TRIGGER)*/
UPDATE eq_list SET titleenglishmap = eqid WHERE titleenglishmap = -9999;
/* Add the euipment title translations  (note that groupid is irrelevant for)*/
INSERT INTO eq_list (title,groupid,languageidmap,titleenglishmap) VALUES
    ('téléphone',(SELECT groupid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'telephone'),(SELECT languageid FROM language WHERE languagename LIKE 'French'),(SELECT eqid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'telephone' )),
    ('telefon',(SELECT groupid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'telephone'),(SELECT languageid FROM language WHERE languagename LIKE 'German'),(SELECT eqid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'telephone' )),
    ('teléfono',(SELECT groupid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'telephone'),(SELECT languageid FROM language WHERE languagename LIKE 'spanish'),(SELECT eqid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'telephone' )),
    ('telefono',(SELECT groupid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'telephone'),(SELECT languageid FROM language WHERE languagename LIKE 'italian'),(SELECT eqid FROM eq_list WHERE title LIKE 'telephone' ))
;

SELECT qty_listid,title,qty_list,languagename  FROM qty_list 
    JOIN eq_list  ON qty_list.qty_listgroupid = eq_list.groupid
    JOIN language ON eq_list.languageidmap = language.languageid
WHERE languagename LIKE 'Spanish'
;

SELECT qty_listid,title,qty_list,languagename  FROM qty_list 
    JOIN eq_list  ON qty_list.qty_listgroupid = eq_list.groupid
    JOIN language ON eq_list.languageidmap = language.languageid
WHERE languagename LIKE 'Italian'
```

- used groupid 1 so results are :-

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Expanding the Previous Answer - Applying the solution via Room**

Following on from the question where the suggestion was to incorporate a language table and changes to the eq_list table. This goes through implemnting the solution via room.

The 3 @Entity annotated classes (i.e. the 3 tables):-

**Language**

```
const val LANGUAGE_TABLE_NAME = "language"
const val LANGUAGE_ID_COLUMN = "languageid"
const val LANGUAGE_NAME_COLUMN = "languagename"
const val LANGUAGE_SHORTNAME_COLUMN = "languageshortname"
//CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS language (languageid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, languagename TEXT UNIQUE, languageshortname TEXT UNIQUE);
@Entity(tableName = LANGUAGE_TABLE_NAME,
    indices = [
        Index(LANGUAGE_NAME_COLUMN, unique = true),
        Index(value = [LANGUAGE_SHORTNAME_COLUMN], unique = true)
    ]
)
data class Language(
    @ColumnInfo(name = LANGUAGE_ID_COLUMN)
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = LANGUAGE_NAME_COLUMN)
    val languageName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = LANGUAGE_SHORTNAME_COLUMN)
    val languageShortName: String
)
```

- const's are recommended as they can reduce the potential for coding mistakes.
- the assumption is that Language Names and codes must be unique (so perhaps UK(AUS), UK(US) for language derivations if needed)

**QT_List**

```
//CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS qty_list (qty_listid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, qty_listgroupid INTEGER, qty_list INTEGER)
const val QTY_TABLE_NAME = "qty_list"
const val QTY_ID_COLUMN = "qty_listid"
const val QTY_GROUP_ID_COLUMN = "qty_listgroupid"
const val QTY_COLUMN = "qty"
@Entity(tableName = QTY_TABLE_NAME)
data class QT_List(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = QTY_ID_COLUMN)
    val id: Long? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = QTY_GROUP_ID_COLUMN, index = true)
    val valgroupId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = QTY_COLUMN)
    val qty: Long
)
```

**EQ_List**

```
//CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eq_list (eqid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, groupid INTEGER, titleenglishmap INTEGER, languageidmap INTEGER REFERENCES language(languageid));
const val EQ_TABLE_NAME = "eq_list"
const val EQID_COLUMN = "eqid"
const val TITLE_COLUMN = "title"
const val GROUPID_COLUMN = "groupid"
const val TITLE_ENGLISH_MAP_COLUMN = "titleenglishmap"
const val LANGUAGE_ID_MAP_COLUMN = "languageidmap"
const val BASE_EQ_VALUE = -9999
//CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS AFTER INSERT ON eq_list WHEN new.languageidmap = -9999 BEGIN UPDATE eq_list SET titleenglishmap = new.eqid WHERE new.titleenglishmap = -9999; END;
const val TRIGGER_SQL = "CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS AFTER INSERT ON ${EQ_TABLE_NAME} " +
        "/* WHEN CAST(new.${LANGUAGE_ID_MAP_COLUMN} AS INTEGER) < CAST(1 AS INTEGER) */ " + //<<<<<<<<< Commented WHEN clause out as it may be version sensitive */
        "BEGIN UPDATE ${EQ_TABLE_NAME} SET $TITLE_ENGLISH_MAP_COLUMN = $EQID_COLUMN WHERE $TITLE_ENGLISH_MAP_COLUMN = ${BASE_EQ_VALUE} ;" +
        "END;"
@Entity(
    tableName = EQ_TABLE_NAME,
    indices = [
        Index(value = [GROUPID_COLUMN]),
        Index(TITLE_ENGLISH_MAP_COLUMN),
        Index(LANGUAGE_ID_MAP_COLUMN)
    ],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Language::class,
            parentColumns = [LANGUAGE_ID_COLUMN],
            childColumns = [LANGUAGE_ID_MAP_COLUMN],
            onDelete = CASCADE,
            onUpdate = CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class EQ_List(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = EQID_COLUMN)
    val id: Long? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = TITLE_COLUMN)
    val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = GROUPID_COLUMN)
    val groupId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = TITLE_ENGLISH_MAP_COLUMN)
    val titleEnglishMap: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = LANGUAGE_ID_MAP_COLUMN)
    val languageIdMap: Long
)
```

- TRIGGER_SQL is a prime example where using const's can simplify the coding.
- Note see **TheDatabase** for implementing the TRIGGER

**QTTranslated** is a POJO class for extracting the translated title (see AllDao and MainActivity for example usage)

```
const val EXPECTED_QTYLISTID_COLUMN = "qtyListId"
const val EXPECTED_TRANSLATEDTITLE_COLUMN = "translatedTitle"
const val EXPECTED_QUANTITY_COLUMN = "qty"
const val EXPECTED_LANGUAGENAME_COLUMN = "languageName"
const val EXPECTED_LANGUAGESHORTNAME_COLUMN = "languageNameShort"
data class QTTranslated(
    val qtyListId: Long,
    val translatedTitle: String,
    val qty: Long,
    val languageName: String,
    val languageNameShort: String
)
```

- note EXPECTED's MUST match the val/var name

The **AllDao** class annotated with @Dao (note abstract calls rather than an interface):-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(language: Language): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(qtList: QT_List): Long

    /* SHOULDN'T BE USED */
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(eqList: EQ_List): Long

    /* For insert Base EQ_List rows (the English title) */
    @Query("INSERT INTO $EQ_TABLE_NAME (" +
            "$TITLE_COLUMN," +
            "$GROUPID_COLUMN," +
            "$LANGUAGE_ID_MAP_COLUMN," +
            "$TITLE_ENGLISH_MAP_COLUMN" +
            ") " +
            "VALUES(" +
            ":title," +
            ":groupId," +
            "(SELECT $LANGUAGE_ID_COLUMN FROM $LANGUAGE_TABLE_NAME WHERE $LANGUAGE_NAME_COLUMN = :languageName)," +
            "$BASE_EQ_VALUE" +
            ")")

    abstract fun insertBaseEQ_List(title: String, groupId: Long,languageName: String = "English"): Long

    /* For inserting the other language versions of the base title */
    @Query("INSERT INTO $EQ_TABLE_NAME (" +
            "$TITLE_COLUMN," +
            "$GROUPID_COLUMN," +
            "$LANGUAGE_ID_MAP_COLUMN," +
            "$TITLE_ENGLISH_MAP_COLUMN" +
            ") " +
            "VALUES(" +
            ":title," +
            "(SELECT $GROUPID_COLUMN FROM $EQ_TABLE_NAME WHERE $TITLE_COLUMN LIKE :baseTitle)," +
            "(SELECT $LANGUAGE_ID_COLUMN FROM $LANGUAGE_TABLE_NAME WHERE $LANGUAGE_NAME_COLUMN LIKE :languageName)," +
            "(SELECT $EQID_COLUMN FROM ${EQ_TABLE_NAME} WHERE ${TITLE_COLUMN} LIKE :baseTitle))")
    abstract fun insertOtherLanguageEQ_List(title: String, baseTitle: String, languageName: String)

    /* TRIGGER alternative (not demonstrated) */
    @Query("UPDATE $EQ_TABLE_NAME SET $TITLE_ENGLISH_MAP_COLUMN = $EQID_COLUMN WHERE $TITLE_ENGLISH_MAP_COLUMN = $BASE_EQ_VALUE")
    abstract fun reconcileBaseEQ_List(): Int

/* The query that gets translated version according to the languagename passed */
    @Query("SELECT " +
            "$QTY_ID_COLUMN AS $EXPECTED_QTYLISTID_COLUMN," +
            "${TITLE_COLUMN} AS $EXPECTED_TRANSLATEDTITLE_COLUMN," +
            "${QTY_COLUMN} AS $EXPECTED_QUANTITY_COLUMN," +
            "${LANGUAGE_NAME_COLUMN} AS $EXPECTED_LANGUAGENAME_COLUMN," +
            "${LANGUAGE_SHORTNAME_COLUMN} AS $EXPECTED_LANGUAGESHORTNAME_COLUMN " +
            "FROM ${QTY_TABLE_NAME} " +
            "JOIN ${EQ_TABLE_NAME} ON ${QTY_TABLE_NAME}.${QTY_GROUP_ID_COLUMN} = ${EQ_TABLE_NAME}.${GROUPID_COLUMN} " +
            "JOIN ${LANGUAGE_TABLE_NAME} ON ${EQ_TABLE_NAME}.${LANGUAGE_ID_MAP_COLUMN} = ${LANGUAGE_TABLE_NAME}.${LANGUAGE_ID_COLUMN} " +
            "WHERE ${LANGUAGE_NAME_COLUMN} LIKE :languageName")
    abstract fun getQTTranslatedList(languageName: String): List<QTTranslated>
}
```

The @Database annotated class **TheDatabase** suitable for demonstration of the Room implementation:-

```
const val DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db"
@Database(entities = [Language::class,EQ_List::class,QT_List::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                    .addCallback(cb)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }

    /* Want to add the Trigger */

    object cb : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        /* onOpen will try to add the trigger every time the database is opened
            although perhaps overkill it will ensure that the trigger always exists
            so is more forgiving of room not knowing about the trigger
        * */

        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onOpen(db)
            db.execSQL(TRIGGER_SQL)
        }
        /* onCreate will only add the trigger when the database is created
            this would be the typical way BUT BEWARE Room doesn't know about the trigger
            if the table is deleted the trigger will be deleted
        * */
        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)
            db.execSQL(TRIGGER_SQL)
        }
    }

}
```

Finally an activity, **MainActivity** to replicate some of the original answer (designed to run just the once):-

```
const val TAG = "DBINFO"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var dbInstance: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        dbInstance = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = dbInstance.getAllDao()

        dao.insert(Language(languageName = "English", languageShortName = "en"))
        dao.insert(Language(languageName = "French", languageShortName = "fr"))
        dao.insert(Language(languageName = "German", languageShortName = "de"))

        dao.insertBaseEQ_List(title = "Television",1)
        dao.insertOtherLanguageEQ_List(title = "Le Tele", baseTitle = "Television","French")
        dao.insertOtherLanguageEQ_List("Fernsehen","Television","German")

        dao.insert(QT_List(valgroupId = 1, qty = 3))
        dao.insert(QT_List(valgroupId = 1, qty = 6))
        dao.insert(QT_List(valgroupId = 1, qty = 8))

        for(q: QTTranslated in dao.getQTTranslatedList("French")) {
            Log.d(TAG,"QT_List id = ${q.qtyListId} Translated Title = ${q.translatedTitle} Quantity = ${q.qty} Language is ${q.languageName}/${q.copy()}")
        }
        for(q: QTTranslated in dao.getQTTranslatedList("English")) {
            Log.d(TAG,"QT_List id = ${q.qtyListId} Translated Title = ${q.translatedTitle} Quantity = ${q.qty} Language is ${q.languageName}/${q.copy()}")
        }
        for(q: QTTranslated in dao.getQTTranslatedList("German")) {
            Log.d(TAG,"QT_List id = ${q.qtyListId} Translated Title = ${q.translatedTitle} Quantity = ${q.qty} Language is ${q.languageName}/${q.copy()}")
        }

        dao.insert(Language(languageName = "Spanish", languageShortName = "es"))
        dao.insert(Language(languageName = "Italian", languageShortName = "it"))

        dao.insertOtherLanguageEQ_List(title = "Televisión", baseTitle = "Television", languageName = "Spanish")
        dao.insertOtherLanguageEQ_List(title = "Television", baseTitle = "Television", languageName = "iTaLiAn")

        for(q: QTTranslated in dao.getQTTranslatedList("sPANISH")) {
            Log.d(TAG,"QT_List id = ${q.qtyListId} Translated Title = ${q.translatedTitle} Quantity = ${q.qty} Language is ${q.languageName}/${q.copy()}")
        }
        for(q: QTTranslated in dao.getQTTranslatedList("ItAlIaN")) {
            Log.d(TAG,"QT_List id = ${q.qtyListId} Translated Title = ${q.translatedTitle} Quantity = ${q.qty} Language is ${q.languageName}/${q.copy()}")
        }
    }
}
```

**Result in the Log**

```
2022-01-17 21:26:48.638 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 1 Translated Title = Le Tele Quantity = 3 Language is French/QTTranslated(qtyListId=1, translatedTitle=Le Tele, qty=3, languageName=French, languageNameShort=fr)
2022-01-17 21:26:48.638 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 2 Translated Title = Le Tele Quantity = 6 Language is French/QTTranslated(qtyListId=2, translatedTitle=Le Tele, qty=6, languageName=French, languageNameShort=fr)
2022-01-17 21:26:48.638 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 3 Translated Title = Le Tele Quantity = 8 Language is French/QTTranslated(qtyListId=3, translatedTitle=Le Tele, qty=8, languageName=French, languageNameShort=fr)
2022-01-17 21:26:48.639 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 1 Translated Title = Television Quantity = 3 Language is English/QTTranslated(qtyListId=1, translatedTitle=Television, qty=3, languageName=English, languageNameShort=en)
2022-01-17 21:26:48.639 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 2 Translated Title = Television Quantity = 6 Language is English/QTTranslated(qtyListId=2, translatedTitle=Television, qty=6, languageName=English, languageNameShort=en)
2022-01-17 21:26:48.639 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 3 Translated Title = Television Quantity = 8 Language is English/QTTranslated(qtyListId=3, translatedTitle=Television, qty=8, languageName=English, languageNameShort=en)
2022-01-17 21:26:48.640 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 1 Translated Title = Fernsehen Quantity = 3 Language is German/QTTranslated(qtyListId=1, translatedTitle=Fernsehen, qty=3, languageName=German, languageNameShort=de)
2022-01-17 21:26:48.640 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 2 Translated Title = Fernsehen Quantity = 6 Language is German/QTTranslated(qtyListId=2, translatedTitle=Fernsehen, qty=6, languageName=German, languageNameShort=de)
2022-01-17 21:26:48.640 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 3 Translated Title = Fernsehen Quantity = 8 Language is German/QTTranslated(qtyListId=3, translatedTitle=Fernsehen, qty=8, languageName=German, languageNameShort=de)
2022-01-17 21:26:48.649 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 1 Translated Title = Televisión Quantity = 3 Language is Spanish/QTTranslated(qtyListId=1, translatedTitle=Televisión, qty=3, languageName=Spanish, languageNameShort=es)
2022-01-17 21:26:48.649 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 2 Translated Title = Televisión Quantity = 6 Language is Spanish/QTTranslated(qtyListId=2, translatedTitle=Televisión, qty=6, languageName=Spanish, languageNameShort=es)
2022-01-17 21:26:48.649 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 3 Translated Title = Televisión Quantity = 8 Language is Spanish/QTTranslated(qtyListId=3, translatedTitle=Televisión, qty=8, languageName=Spanish, languageNameShort=es)
2022-01-17 21:26:48.650 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 1 Translated Title = Television Quantity = 3 Language is Italian/QTTranslated(qtyListId=1, translatedTitle=Television, qty=3, languageName=Italian, languageNameShort=it)
2022-01-17 21:26:48.650 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 2 Translated Title = Television Quantity = 6 Language is Italian/QTTranslated(qtyListId=2, translatedTitle=Television, qty=6, languageName=Italian, languageNameShort=it)
2022-01-17 21:26:48.650 D/DBINFO: QT_List id = 3 Translated Title = Television Quantity = 8 Language is Italian/QTTranslated(qtyListId=3, translatedTitle=Television, qty=8, languageName=Italian, languageNameShort=it)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest having the database as follows:

EQ_LIST

```
eq_id | group_id | title_en | title_fr | title_de 
  1,       1,         tv ,    la télé,   Fernseher
```

and also store the user selected language or default language on shared preferences or maybe another table, and according to user selected language you fetch accordingly

Comment: And what if I would like to add another languages later?

Comment: you add another column, but if the table isn't on server side then its better to store on Strings.xml file and use Android localization

Comment: It is not on a server now, but it can change later, can happen later it will need to export these data to cloud