# How to properly store multilingual content in an android application?

Tags: android, android-room, android-file, android-database

I'm making a language learning app that can work offline. But I don't understand how to properly store the content.
Now I have these options:

1. Create one table for all languages. For example, a table of words and get the desired words by language tag. But then it seems to me that the table will be too large, and in some languages, words may require additional information that is not available in other languages, and then many records will have empty columns.
2. Create separate tables for each language. But if the user, while studying one language, decides to switch to another, then you need to load new data from another table and I don’t understand how to change DAOs(i use room) in runtime.
3. Scatter everything in files and folders. But then any accidental change can cause the application to work incorrectly. And I don’t know how to implement pagination and UI updates in case of some file changes, for example, a new word has been added to the file.

Comment: You may wish to consider looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69056684/how-to-make-database-for-vocabulary-list-app-with-multiple-languages-like-google/69060539#69060539 and perhaps also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70725381/how-to-make-database-for-multilanguage-list-app/70736799#70736799

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.